# the different result between node and chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm learn es6 and i have fund a strange question
'this' is different between node and chrome environment
in node

```
var id = 32;
function foo(){
  setTimeout(()=> {
    // console.log('id=>',this.id);
    console.log('id=>',this === global);
    // console.log(this)
    console.log('*---------*');
  },100);
}

function foo1(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    // console.log('id !=>', this.id);
    console.log('id !=>',this === global);
    // console.log(this);
    console.log('*---------*');
  }, 100);
}
foo();
foo1();
foo.call({id:42});
foo1.call({id: 33});
```

in chrome

```
var id = 32;
function foo(){
  setTimeout(()=> {
    // console.log('id=>',this.id);
    console.log('id=>',this === window);
    // console.log(this);
  },100);
}

function foo1(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    // console.log('id !=>', this.id);
    console.log('id !=>',this === window);
    // console.log(this);
  }, 100);
}

foo();
foo1();
foo.call({id:42});
foo1.call({id: 33});
```

the result in node is

```
 true false false false
```

in chrome this result is

```
 true true false true
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine each example separately.

1. `foo();`

   The callback function is an arrow function which doesn't have its own context so `this` refers to the global context which is `global` for node environment and `window` for browser. Thus you get `true` independently of environment.
2. `foo.call({id:42});`

   In this case you pass a context object which is `{id: 42}`. Similar to the previous example as long as callback is an arrow function and does not have its own context `this` refers to the parent context (which is `{id: 42}`) and that's why you get `false` for both node and browser environments.
3. `foo1(); and foo1.call({id: 42})` in browser.

   The main difference of `foo1` function is that a callback is a normal function which has its own context. For browser it doesn't matter either the `foo1` function is called on a global context or the context you passed. In your case the callback function will always has its own one and it will be `window`. That's why you get `true` for both these cases in browser.
4. `foo1(); and foo1.call({id: 42})` in node env.

   Situation in node env is pretty the same. The context of callback function is shadowed from the global context or the context you pass. However, if you check what `this` refers to, you'll see that it is a `Timeout` not `global`. That's why you get `false` for both these cases in node environment.